# php symfony 3.4 several firewalls no route found

Tags: php, symfony

I have been using Symfony 2 and 3 in my progect with several firewalls. In our project we can login users with 2 different ways: with LDAP and as usual through a mysql database. For these purposes we used 2 firewalls (main for LDAP access and main_2 for mysql login) with the following configuration:

```
//security.yml

security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_GOD: ROLE_GOD
    ROLE_SECURITY_AUDITOR: ROLE_SECURITY_AUDITOR 
providers:
    ldap_user_provider:
         id: app.ldap_user_provider
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
firewalls:
    main_2:
        pattern: ^/special
        provider: fos_userbundle
        form_login:
            check_path: /special/login_check
            login_path: /special/login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            use_referer:     true
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /sections
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: fos_authentication_handler
            failure_handler: fos_authentication_handler
            require_previous_session: false
        logout:
            handlers: [appbundle_logoutlistener]
            path:   /special/logout #fos_user_security_logout
            target: /special/login
            invalidate_session: true
        anonymous:    true
        context: my_context
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        #remote_user:
            #provider: ldap_user_provider
        provider: ldap_user_provider
        form_login_ldap:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            service: ldap

            dn_string: '{username}@my.local'
            #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            use_referer:     true
            #default_target_path: /home
            #always_use_default_target_path: true
            success_handler: ldap_authentication_handler
            failure_handler: ldap_authentication_handler
            require_previous_session: false
#           form_login:
#                provider: fos_userbundle
#                always_use_default_target_path: true
#                default_target_path: /home
#                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:
             handlers: [appbundle_logoutlistener]
             path:   /logout #fos_user_security_logout
             target: /
             invalidate_session: true
        anonymous:    true
        context: my_context
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/special/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Everything worked fine until we upgraded to Symfony 3.4 and now when I try to access the route `/special/login` I get page not found error. The route `special` does not appear in `debug:router` either. Any ideas how to fix this?
Thank you.

**UPD_1**

In order to get it work I had to modify the routing file of FOSUserBundle, like this:

```
// vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing 
http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

<route id="fos_user_security_login" path="/special/login" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">fos_user.security.controller:loginAction</default>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_security_check" path="/special/login_check" methods="POST">
    <default key="_controller">fos_user.security.controller:checkAction</default>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_security_logout" path="/special/logout" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">fos_user.security.controller:logoutAction</default>
</route>

</routes>
```

but I need to override these routes in order to get them inside my code, not in vendor folder. Any ideas how to do that?

Thank you

**UPD_2**

moved routing into `AppBundle` and updated `app/config/routing.yml`, issue closed

Comment: No useful errors/warnings leading up to the 404?

Comment: no, just regular `request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /special/login"" at /var/www/html/public/dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 139 `